# When connecting to the discord gateway, I get an error that my websocket has been closed

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to make a discord bot in python but discord.py doesn't give me the level of control I need so I'm making a custom API. I am using the "websocket-client" module. I have gone through the discord documentation, and I can't find the problem. For some reason, it's giving me an error when I run this code:

```
import requests
from websocket import create_connection
import json
import time
from threading import Thread

token = "<my token>"

class DiscordBot:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
        self.header = {"authorization": token, "content-type":"application/json"}

    def connect(self):
        self.ws = create_connection("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=9&encoding=json")
        event = self.__recievejsonresponse__()
        self.heartbeat_interval = event["d"]["heartbeat_interval"]/1000
        heartbeatProc = Thread(target=self.heartbeat)
        heartbeatProc.start()
        payload = {
            "op":2,
            "d":{
                "token":self.token,
                "intents":8,

                "properties":{
                    "os":"linux",
                    "browser":"chromium",
                    "device":"pc"
                },
            }
        }
        self.__sendjsonrequest__(payload)
        self.__recieveloop__()
    
    def __recieveloop__(self):
        while True:
            event = self.__recievejsonresponse__()
            print(event)
            self.prevEvent = event            
            try:
                #print(f"{author}:{content}")
                op_code = event["op"]
                if op_code == 11:
                    print("heartbeat recievedd")
            except:
                pass

    def heartbeat(self):
        print("heartbeating")
        heartbeatJSON = {
                "op": 1,
                "d": "null"
            }
        self.__sendjsonrequest__(heartbeatJSON)
        while True:
            time.sleep(self.heartbeat_interval)
            heartbeatJSON = {
                "op": 1,
                "d": "null"
            }
            self.__sendjsonrequest__(heartbeatJSON)

    def __recievejsonresponse__(self):
        response = self.ws.recv()
        if response:
            return json.loads(response)
        
    def __sendjsonrequest__(self, request):
        self.ws.send(json.dumps(request))
```

While running this code, I end up with the error

```
{'t': None, 's': None, 'op': 11, 'd': None}
heartbeat recievedd
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Downloads\learn.py", line 153, in <module>
    myBot.connect()
  File "c:\Downloads\learn.py", line 34, in connect
    self.__recieveloop__()
  File "c:\Downloads\learn.py", line 38, in __recieveloop__
    event = self.__recievejsonresponse__()
  File "c:\Downloads\learn.py", line 110, in __recievejsonresponse__
    response = self.ws.recv()
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 362, in recv
    opcode, data = self.recv_data()
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 385, in recv_data
    opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 406, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 445, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 338, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 294, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 373, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 529, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "C:\Apps\Python310\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 122, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bot receives the heartbeat request, but doesn't reply to it. This causes discord to close the websocket since it thinks you stopped responding, so the next `__recievejsonresponse__()` fails because the websocket closed.

Just responding to the heartbeat should be enough to fix the issue, but you might want to add additional disconnect handling in case the connection ever breaks down.

Comment: Isn't that what the heartbeat() function is for? Could you please clarify what I am meant to change to make my code work?

Comment: @birdwhocancode not sure if your code even worked in the first place without seeing more logs, adding a timestamp to the logs would be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

the Heartbeat ACK (opcode 11) is, as its name suggests, an acknowledgment of receipt from the discord server, you should not respond to it, however, as it is mentioned in the documentation, you must specify the "d" field for each heartbeast by the last field "s" you received if you received any else "d" may be null as you did in your code, I'm not sure.
confirm if it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).